# Storing sort function changes results

Tags: javascript, sorting

I wrote a function to sort my custom card class and it worked exactly as intended. I then tried to save the function for repeated use, but once I did, using it gave completely different results.

```
myCards.sort(function(a, b){return card.CountRanks(fiveCards, true)[a.rank] != card.CountRanks(fiveCards, true)[b.rank] ? card.CountRanks(fiveCards, true)[b.rank] - card.CountRanks(fiveCards, true)[a.rank] : a.rank != b.rank ? b.rank - a.rank : b.suit - a.suit});
//Sorts exactly as intended

myCards.sort(card.pokerSort());
//Sorts quite differently

static pokerSort(){ //Within the card class
    return function(a, b){return card.CountRanks(fiveCards, true)[a.rank] != card.CountRanks(fiveCards, true)[b.rank] ? card.CountRanks(fiveCards, true)[b.rank] - card.CountRanks(fiveCards, true)[a.rank] : a.rank != b.rank ? b.rank - a.rank : b.suit - a.suit};
}
```

What is the reason for this behavior? Is there a way to save a sorting function and have it work the way I intend?

Comment: please add some data and the scheme which you are sorting.

Comment: `pokerSort` is a function which returns a function. But it's not supposed to return a function, it's supposed to take two arguments and return a number.

Comment: You would have to call it like `myCards.sort(card.pokerSort());` with the way it is written....

Comment: `save the function for repeated use`  Ironically creating a function to create a function doesn't do that.. :)

Comment: Do you dislike \n's or do u just hate readable code?

Comment: Omitting the () after pokerSort was a mistake in typing the question. I had them in my code when I first encountered this problem.

Comment: The bigger problem I'm seeing now myself is using the `fiveCards` variable inside `pokerSort`, but I don't see a way around it. There's no way to reference the entire array being sorted in a sort function, is there? Just two elements at a time?

Answer (score 2):

`pokerSort` itself has to take the parameters:

```
 static pokerSort(a, b) {
```

Or you have to pass the result of calling it (the function taking a and b):

```
 myCards.sort(card.pokerSort())
```

---

Notes:

By convention, Classes start with an uppercase letter (`Card`), while methods do not (`countRanks`).

Newlines do make your code way mote readable.

The OR operator is really useful if you want to replace 0 with something else:

```
 static pokerSort(a, b) {
   const ranks = Card.countRanks(fiveCards, true);
   return (
     ranks[a.rank] - ranks[b.rank] ||  
     b.rank - a.rank ||
     b.suit - a.suit
  );
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

BTW, you coud chain the order of sorting.

```
card.pokerSort = function (a, b) {
    return card.CountRanks(fiveCards, true)[a.rank] - card.CountRanks(fiveCards, true)[b.rank]
        || b.rank - a.rank
        || b.suit - a.suit;
};
```